# quick typing between multipe EditTexts not working

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I have 3 EditTexts, and each one of them can contain one char and once user has input that char we just go to the next editText. The logic works welll except if you try to type the text really fast then first edit is populated correctly and cursor is moved to next edit but the next char that is typed is lost. I have no idea why this happens or how I could fix this issue, any suggestion welcome.

Code:

TextWatcher class:

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

    if(editable.length() == LEFT_EDITOR_MAX_LENGTH && Character.isLetter(editable.charAt(LEFT_EDITOR_MAX_LENGTH - 1))){
            fragment.goToNextView();
        } else if(editable.length() > LEFT_EDITOR_MAX_LENGTH - 1){
        //if (editable.length() > LEFT_EDITOR_MAX_LENGTH + 1) {
            fragment.removeInvalidChar();
    }

}
```

DialogFragment fragment (normal not compatibility fragment)

.....

```
protected void goToNextView() {
      if (edi1.hasFocus()) {
        edi1.removeTextChangedListener(watcher1);
        edi2.requestFocus();
    } else if (edi2.hasFocus()) {
        edi2.removeTextChangedListener(watcher2);
        edi3.requestFocus();
    } else if (edi3.hasFocus()) {
        edi3.removeTextChangedListener(watcher3);
        sendPassphrase();
    }
}

protected EditText getFocusedEditText() {
    if (edi1.hasFocus()) {
        return edi1;
    } else if (edi2.hasFocus()) {
        return edi2;
    } else {
        return edi3;
    }
}

void removeInvalidChar() {
    EditText focusedEditText = getFocusedEditText();

    updateEmptyTextField(focusedEditText, "");

}

private void updateEmptyTextField(EditText editText, String emptyString) {
    editText.setText(emptyString);
    editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());
}
```

thanks

Comment: It would be good if you could handle this case, but you don`t have to worry too much about it because user will figure it out and handle it manually instead of you

Comment: yes the user could type slower but I still want to try to fix the issue, plus understand why the problem occurs, why the chars get lost!

Comment: Im guessing the user starts typing before the listener is attached.. Do you realy need to remove these listeners?

Comment: @Loma Roma: I don't think this is the issue sonce textWatcher does not populate editText with the chars, Android should do it it himself, so I don't see how removing the watchers would have an impact.